# gitlab-runner commands lifecycle for restarting runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to configure a runner and using the reference https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/

but It's not clear what the command lifecycle is for 
run/start/install/register

- Should register be called once or every time I reboot the system. What about install and start?
- To restart a runner should I do `stop` ,
  `uninstall` and then `install`
  `start`
  `run`?
- Should I have to `run` it or `start` would have the same effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The steps for getting the runner up and running (and surviving reboots) should be something along the lines of:

1. [Download the runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html)
2. [Register the runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html)
3. Install the runner and service with:

```
gitlab-runner install
gitlab-runner start
```

The machine should now be ready to serve as a runner, and nothing else needs to be done to it (until you want to update the runner...).

---

> Should register be called once or every time I reboot the system. What about install and start?

Register should be called once, this creates a `config.toml` file which saves the configuration of the registration across reboots. The files location changes depending on how it was registered. IE on Linux, registering a `shell` runner with `sudo`, would save the `config.toml` file to `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`.

With regards to `install` and `start`, also only needs to be run once and survives across reboots. The `install` installs the GitLab Runner as a service, and `start` just runs it the first time.

> To restart a runner should I do stop , uninstall and then install start run?

Just do a [gitlab-runner restart](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#gitlab-runner-restart).

> Should I have to run it or start would have the same effect?

If you have done an `install` and `start` you have no need to use `run`. I believe `run` is only for one use (on the open terminal) for debugging jobs. `start` is for the service on the machine.

HTH.